# Seleccionar nombre de la columna que tiene el máximo valor de una fila en PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Tengo esta tabla en PostgreSQL

| id | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| X | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 |
| Y | 9 | 4 | 10 | 1 |
| Z | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

Y necesito identificar, para cada fila, cuál es la columna que contenga el valor máximo. Es decir, añadir a la tabla otra columna que indique el nombre de la columna con el valor máximo. Así

| id | A | B | C | D | Máx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | D |
| X | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | A |
| Y | 9 | 4 | 10 | 1 | C |
| Z | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | D |

Todo intento con la función `MAX()` me devuelve el valor máximo, no cuál es la columna que lo contiene. ¿Es posible hacer esta consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un compañero ha resuelto el problema

```
SELECT X3.ID,X3.A,X3.B,X3.C,X3.D,MAX(X3.COD) AS CODIGO,X3.VALOR1
FROM (
SELECT Z1.*, X2.COD, X2.VALOR1
FROM (
    SELECT ID, MAX(VALOR0) AS TOPE
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, A AS VALOR0
        FROM z_tmp Z0 UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, B AS VALOR0
        FROM z_tmp Z0 UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, C AS VALOR0
        FROM z_tmp Z0 UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, D AS VALOR0
        FROM z_tmp Z0
    ) X0
    GROUP BY ID
    ) X1
INNER JOIN z_tmp Z1 on Z1.ID=X1.ID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, A AS VALOR1, 'A' AS COD
    FROM z_tmp Z2 UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, B AS VALOR1, 'B' AS COD
    FROM z_tmp Z2 UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, C AS VALOR1, 'C' AS COD
    FROM z_tmp Z2 UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, D AS VALOR1, 'D' AS COD
    FROM z_tmp Z2
    ) X2 ON (X2.ID=Z1.ID AND X2.VALOR1=X1.TOPE)
) X3
GROUP BY X3.ID,X3.A,X3.B,X3.C,X3.D,X3.VALOR1
ORDER BY X3.ID
```

Comment: ¡No olvides [edit] y explicar cómo funciona la consulta! Tal vez para vos sea claro, pero para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar, no.

Comment: qué va, para mí no es claro en absoluto, lamentablemente, pero funciona.